# CKEditor won't display my textarea value attribute

Tags: php, mysql, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm retrieving text from a database that is supposed to serve as the value for my CKEditor field.

Here's my code:

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/34.2.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
<textarea id="editor" rows="6" name="post-body" value="<?php echo html_entity_decode($post['content']) ?>"></textarea>  
<script>
    ClassicEditor
        .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
        .catch( error => {
            console.error( error );
        } );
</script>
```

However, when the page is rendered, the CKEditor field is blank; the contents of my value attribute isn't displayed.

What can be causing this? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Textarea doesn't have the attribute `value`.

The content goes between `<textarea>` and `</textarea>` or when you want to display a placeholder you have to use the attribute `placeholder`.

So either

```
<textarea id="editor" rows="6" name="post-body"><?php echo html_entity_decode($post['content']) ?></textarea>
```

or

```
<textarea id="editor" rows="6" name="post-body" placeholder="<?php echo html_entity_decode($post['content']) ?>"></textarea>
```

See [Textarea on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)

See [Value attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes)